# p:dataGrid: Is grid-layout with 4-2-1 columns possible?

Tags: primefaces

I have a responsive DataGrid with 4 columns.

```
<p:dataGrid value="#{myController.objList}" var="obj" layout="grid" columns="4">

    <p:outputPanel>
      <h:outputText value="Label 1: " />
      <h:outputText value="#{obj.field1}" />
    </p:outputPanel>

    <p:outputPanel>
      <h:outputText value="Label 2: " />
      <h:outputText value="#{obj.field2}" />
    </p:outputPanel>

</p:dataGrid>
```

It depends on screen width (approximately 640px) when DataGrid is switching from 4 to 1 column. My intention is, depending on screen width, first to switch from 4 to 2 columns and then from 2 to 1 column, like it is possible with PrimeFaces GridCSS.

- Is that possible with DataGrid?
- Can I change CSS by using media queries?
- Is it possible to integrate ArrayList into GridCSS?

Comment: 1: Did you try? 2: Did you try? 3: No idea what you mean...

Answer (score 1):

Changing dataGrid style classes with media queries makes it working as requested.

```
.ui-grid-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .ui-datagrid-column {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .ui-datagrid-column {
        width: 50% !important;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
    .ui-datagrid-column {
        width: 25% !important;
    }
}
```